# JMeter- Reading One row of CSV file to Multiple rows of another csv file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

How can I loop one csv file to another csv file in JMeter, where the first csv file contains all the login data and the other csv file contains the transaction data. I am supposed to run where 1 teller should process 30 transaction.

Comment: that sounds similar to [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24476329/4648586), two parameters with different CSV input.. i could be wrong though.

Comment: I have tried that configuration but it does not work on my test plan

Answer (score 2):

Go for [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function.

You will not be able to use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as it is a [Configuration Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) and according to the JMeter Test Elements [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) all the configuration elements are being initialised at the very beginning of the test while your requirement is to read data based on user dynamically.

Check out [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article for comprehensive information on using __CSVRead() function